# Cannot install Monet DB Lite for R Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: r, monetdblite

I try running:

```
 install.packages("MonetDBLite")
```

in R. However, I get the following error:

```
 cc1: error: -Wformat-security ignored without -Wformat [-Werror=format-security]
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 Makevars:194: recipe for target 'build/objects/monetdblite/common/stream.o' failed
 make: *** [build/objects/monetdblite/common/stream.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘MonetDBLite’
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Output from sessionInfo() below:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 17.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 
     LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8     LC_NAME=C                     LC_ADDRESS=C
     LC_TELEPHONE=C           LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be resolved with the latest version of MonetDBLite on CRAN, 0.5.1.